# in which units does tar --checkpoint measure?

Tags: tar, options

GNU `tar` offers the option `--checkpoint` where a message should be printed each `checkpoint`reached.

**Question:**: In what does `--checkpoint` measure?

My best guess is Bytes.

I wasn't able to find a hint in the `man` nor the `info` nor in [GNU's documentation on `tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC47).

The OS is Linux, I use Bash and I use `tar (GNU tar) 1.26`

Comment: I have not enough reputation to just comment, but I wanted to link this script which I found very helpful in this context: https://gist.github.com/ng-pe/b59eca23c603e70145e4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From `info tar`:

> The checkpoint facility is enabled using the following option:
>
> `--checkpoint[=N]`: Schedule checkpoints before writing or reading each Nth record. The default value for N is 10.

So the default value for `N` is 10 *records*. But what is a *record* anyway?

In truth, the meaning of *record* above is not easily discerned. There are no hints or pointers in the `checkpoint` section of the `info tar` manual. Still if you go further on you'll eventually come to the section on `blocks` and `blocking-factor`.

> The data in an archive is grouped into blocks, which are 512 bytes.
>   Blocks are read and written in whole number multiples called *records*.
>   The number of blocks in a *record* *(i.e., the size of a **record** in units
>   of 512 bytes)* is called the *blocking factor*.  The
>   `--blocking-factor=512-SIZE` (`-b 512-SIZE`) option specifies the
>   *blocking factor* of an archive.  The **default blocking factor is
>   typically 20 *(i.e., 10240 bytes)***, but can be specified at installation.
>
> To find out the blocking factor of an existing archive, use `tar --list
>   --file=ARCHIVE-NAME`.  This may not work on some devices.

So each `checkpoint record` is so-many `blocks`. This is definable via GNU `tar`'s `-b` or `--blocking-factor=[recordsize]` option. If you do:

```
tar --show-defaults
```

You should get output like:

```
--format=gnu -f- -b20 --quoting-style=escape --rmt-command=/usr/lib/tar/rmt
```

Which would indicate that one record is 20 blocks.

You can also directly specify the record size in terms of bytes like:

> `--record-size=SIZE[SUF]`
>        Instructs `tar` to use *SIZE* bytes per record when accessing the archive.  The argument can be suffixed with a *size suffix*, e.g. `--record-size=10K` for 10 Kilobytes.

Comment: from the GNU Manual "*the term member to refer only to the members of an archive*" (-> https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC3) and then… whatever. Confusing: Yes. Solved: Yes. Thanks!